# how to do snowfalkes DB JNDI connection in Websphere Liberty application server

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, websphere-liberty

Is there a way to configure snowflakes connection pooling in websphere application serve.
I tried below config inside server.xml file. But not working.

```
<dataSource id="SnowflakeDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/BM_SF" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
<properties db="abcd" schema="_TARGET" URL="jdbc:snowflake://adpdc_cdl.us-east-1.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com" user="****" password="****" />
<jdbcDriver libraryRef="DatacloudLibs" javax.sql.DataSource="net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeBasicDataSource"/>
</dataSource>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, the configuration that you have configures WebSphere Application Server Liberty's connection pooling for a Snowflake data source, rather than Snowflake's connection pooling.

The configuration that you have looks mostly pretty good.

When I looked up the [SnowflakeBasicDataSource](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/net/snowflake/client/jdbc/SnowflakeBasicDataSource.java) class that you are using, I can see that it has a property called "databaseName", not "db", so you'll need to switch that in your configuration.

You will also need to configure one of the jdbc-4.x features in Liberty if you haven't already, and if you plan to look it up in JNDI (vs inject it), you'll need the jndi-1.0 feature.

Here is an example with some corrections:

```
  <featureManager>
    <feature>jdbc-4.2</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    ... your other features here
  </featureManager>

  <dataSource id="SnowflakeDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/BM_SF" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <properties databaseName="abcd" schema="_TARGET" URL="jdbc:snowflake://adpdc_cdl.us-east-1.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com" user="****" password="****" />
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="DatacloudLibs" javax.sql.DataSource="net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeBasicDataSource"/>
  </dataSource>
```

If this still doesn't work, look into your definition of the DatacloudLibs library to ensure that it is properly pointing at the Snowflake JDBC driver, and if it still doesn't work, post the error message that you see in case it helps to determine the cause.